# How can I ignore the first row in a table I'm reading with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I've got a JavaScript app this is looping through an HTML table - I can output the results and see that much is working. But I need it to ignore the first row of the table which is the header. I'm getting really confused by the looping logic, any help would be appreciated.

I've tried experimenting with the value of i at the start of the for loop, but that is producing weird results.

Here is my JavaScript:

```
 r = document.getElementById("input_table").rows;
 for(i=1, e=0; i < r.length - 1; i++)
 {

   if( r[i].cells[1].childNodes[0].nodeName == "INPUT" )
     r[i].cells[1].childNodes[0].value = i < ps.length ? ps[i] : "";
}
```

Comment: Can you add the html you're obtaining a reference to? i.e. the full html for the `input_table` element. I need to know what you're looping through to check how your logic may be failing.

Comment: Sure! 

```html
    <table class="table" id="input_table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th scope="col">Party</th>
          <th scope="col">Vote Share %</th>
          <th scope="col">Electorate Seats</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tr>
        <td scope="row">Apples</td>
        <td><input type="text" ></td>
        <td><input type="text" ></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td scope="row">Oranages</td>
        <td><input type="text" ></td>
        <td><input type="text" ></td>
      </tr>
```

Comment: In your JavaScript you're using a ternary conditional statement. The condition of that statement looks off: `r[i].cells[1].childNodes[0].value = i < ps.length` what are you trying to check with this line?

Answer (score 1):

You can start with i =2 in your for loop instead of i = 1

Answer (score 0):

If you're wanting to ignore anything in the `<theader>`, you should wrap everything not in the header in a `<tbody>` and get a reference to that instead

**html**

```
<table class="table" id="input_table"> 
  <thead> 
    <tr> 
      <th scope="col">Party</th> 
      <th scope="col">Vote Share %</th> 
      <th scope="col">Electorate Seats</th> 
    </tr> 
  </thead> 
  <tbody>
  <tr> 
    <td scope="row">Apples</td> 
    <td><input type="text" ></td> 
    <td><input type="text" ></td> 
  </tr> 
  <tr> 
    <td scope="row">Oranages</td> 
    <td><input type="text" ></td> 
    <td><input type="text" ></td> 
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**JavaScript**

```
r = document.getElementById("input_table").getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0].rows;
console.log('r: ', r)
for(i=0; i < r.length; i++){
   if( r[i].cells[1].childNodes[0].nodeName == "INPUT" ) {
     r[i].cells[1].childNodes[0].value = i < ps.length ? ps[i] : "";
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, I think what you want is to use `i` for the html row `r[i]`... and `e` for data array `ps[e]`

```
r = document.getElementById("input_table").rows;
for(i=1, e=0; i < r.length - 1; i++, e++)
{

    if( r[i].cells[1].childNodes[0].nodeName == "INPUT" )
        r[i].cells[1].childNodes[0].value = e < ps.length ? ps[e] : "";
}
```